# Dealing with strings amidst int in csv file, None value

Tags: python, string, csv, nonetype

I'm reading in data from a csv file where some of the values are "None". The values that are being read in are then contained in a list.

The list is the passed to a function which requires all values within the list to be in int() format.

However I can't apply this with the "None" string value being present.  I've tried replacing the "None" with None, or with "" but that hasn't worked, it results in an error. The data in the list also needs to stay in the same position so I cant just completely ignore it all together.

I could replace all "None" with 0 but None != 0 really.

EDIT: I've added my code so hopefully it'll make a bit more sense. Trying to create a line chart from data in csv file:

```
import csv
import sys
from collections import Counter
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightSolarizedStyle
from operator import itemgetter

#Read in file to data variable and set header variable
filename = sys.argv[1]
data = []
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = reader.next()
    data = [row for row in reader]

#count rows in spreadsheet (minus header)
row_count = (sum(1 for row in data))-1

#extract headers which I want to use
headerlist = []
for x in header[1:]:    
    headerlist.append(x)

#initialise line chart in module pygal. set style, title, and x axis labels using headerlist variable   
line_chart = pygal.Line(style = LightSolarizedStyle)
line_chart.title = 'Browser usage evolution (in %)'
line_chart.x_labels = map(str, headerlist)

#create lists for data from spreadsheet to be put in to
empty1 = []
empty2 = []

#select which data i want from spreadsheet
for dataline in data:
    empty1.append(dataline[0])
    empty2.append(dataline[1:-1])

#DO SOMETHING TO "NONE" VALUES IN EMPTY TWO SO THEY CAN BE PASSED TO INT CONVERTER ASSIGNED TO EMPTY 3

#convert all items in the lists, that are in the list of empty two to int
empty3 = [[int(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in empty2]

#add data to chart line by line
count = -1
for dataline in data:
    while count < row_count:
        count += 1
        line_chart.add(empty1[count], [x for x in empty3[count]])

#function that only takes int data
line_chart.render_to_file("browser.svg")
```

There will be a lot of inefficiencies or weird ways of doing things, trying to slowly learn.

The above script gives chart:[image: Browser Use %]

With all the Nones set as 0, bu this doesn't really reflect the existence of Chrome pre a certain date. Thanks

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can only offer limited help.

It sounds like you need to utilize [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval).

```
import ast

csvread = csv.reader(file)
list = []
for row in csvread:
    list.append(ast.literal_eval(row[0]))
```

Comment: this may be the right answer, but I am not sure it would work, given `The list is the passed to a function which requires all values within the list to be in int() format.`